# Disable Command-Period as Cancel

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, shortcut

I have recently replaced my MacBook with a newer one, and now the key bindings I have in some applications that are bound to Command-Period no longer work (and instead invoke the "Cancel" action - as described [here](http://osxdaily.com/2014/04/05/cancel-button-keyboard-shortcut-mac-osx/)).

I can't find this command in the **System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts** settings, and attempting to bind Command+Period as an **App Shortcut** invokes the correct action, but then immediately performs "Cancel" again (so it adds an additional action, it doesn't replace the default).

The keyboard bindings that used to work, are managed directly in the application (JetBrains).

Comment: Did you ever find this one out?

Comment: @Magnus, no I never did figure it out. I had to shift my keyboard shortcuts to a different keyboard combination.